# Combine different content inside tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build such construction using jQuery:

```html
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
```

My jQuery code, which is responsible for this line, looks like that:

```
var a2 = $('<a>').attr("href", "add_to_cart:" + item['id']).text('Add to cart');
a2.addClass("btn btn-default add-to-cart");
var i1 = $('<i></i>');
i1.addClass("fa fa-shopping-cart");
a2.append(i1);
```

But result does not contain `<i>` element.

I tried to append `<i>` using `.html` function, but in this case text disappears.
How to make `<a>` element contain both tag and text after it?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: If you want `<i>` was before text you should use `prepend` — `a2.prepend(i1);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked, I thought that this function has different effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hahaha you forgot the last one...

```
$(".test").html(a2);
```

and the parent content

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var a2 = $('<a>').attr("href", "add_to_cart:").text('Add to cart');
 a2.addClass("btn btn-default add-to-cart");
 var i1 = $('<i>iiiiiiiiiiii</i>');
 i1.addClass("fa fa-shopping-cart");
 a2.prepend(i1);

 $(".test").html(a2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test"></div>
```